# Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.zza

Tags: android-studio, firebase, dependencias

[[image: Error al exportar apk, si compila[![][1]][1][1]]

Error al exportar apk, si compila, Investigué y segun es un problema de duplicado de dependencias de firebase.

[image: Error al exportar la apk. Investigué y segun es un problema de duplicado de dependencias de firebase]

[image: Error al exportar apk, si compila]
[image: Investigué y segun es un problema de duplicado de dependencias de firebase]

Intente solucionarlo con el codigo:

```
             implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision') {
                     exclude group: "com.google.android.gms", module: "play-services-auth-base"
```

}

*Esta linea me deja exportar el apk como antes pero al momento de ejecutar la app en el dispositivo se cierra la aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Actualiza las librerias de `database`, `core` y `ml kit`

```
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:19.0.3'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
```

En tu build gradle de proyecto, fijate si no tienes desactualizado google play services

Comment: Gastón Saillén

Actualice las librerias, compila

Pero marca error al querer exportar el apk

Answer (score 0):

Gastón Saillén

actualice las librerias

Compila pero marca error al querer exportar el apk

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Compila pero marca error al querer exportar el apk]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]